# how to create application for video sharing or live video view between two iphones

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, video-streaming, xmpp

I am creating application which is having functionality like 1 person can view video live from another iPhone, i.e. one iphone is recording and and another is viewing the same, as we do with FACE TIME, but this things to be performed by our own server.

I come to know to USE XMPP client, and also we can use google Api , but how to use and what else things are required to create such kind of application ?

Also shall we need to create own server side part or we can hire other servers , like google/gtalk or any other which is already ready.

please guide me what other things are required for the same.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that for connecting 2 devices together [**GStreamer**](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) is one of the best choices: it's broadly used and there's a lot of materials/docs on it.

GStreamer has a pipeline architecture that inspired by DirectShow and Quicktime, and it provides a command-line tool named **gst-launch** that allows you to create a pipeline and quickly test several components of the library together.

[This message](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Stream-on-iPad-iPhone-Android-td2336486.html), shares some interesting info on **how to stream video directly from the iPhone camera using gst-launch**, while receiving the data on a PC through VLC. Which means, 50% of what you are looking for is already done.

**Another option**, also demonstrated in that [message](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Stream-on-iPad-iPhone-Android-td2336486.html), is to **use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)**.

Comment: thanks for the answer... but can we use HTTP Live streaming for the same for both Upstream and downstream , can you suggest something for it, as we can use AVCaptureSession, that I know, but using this how to upstream video using the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to advocate [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org), which has been successfully migrated onto iOS.
What you need to do is:
1. rewrite ffserver, use camera input as the video source, and encode it by H.264/MPEG-4 encoder
2. rewrite ffplay, so that it can display video on iOS devices. The network protocol and video decoder part are ready.

Comment: How we upstream CMsamplebuffer from iphone to server